# Как сделать, чтобы не обрезался текст в плейсхолдере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

а просто переносился текст
в мобилке сильно обрезается

```css
 input {
   display: block;
   font-size: 25px;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон для заказа обратной связи">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну предположу, что из за  padding  ему не хватает место. К тому же играет роль и  font-size. Киньте полный пример, что бы потыкать. Ещё потыкайте в сторону white-space

Comment: так выше ж есть пример на фиддле

Comment: input  - это однострочное текстовое поле

Comment: @soledar10: само поле для ввода - да, однострочное. Но, _placeholder_ более гибок ;-)

Comment: @UModeL.  покажи пожалуйста пример

Comment: в данном случае необходимо использовать textarea. Пример https://jsfiddle.net/1mLfdqw9/

Comment: @soledar10: смотрим пример. Комментируем. Открыт к критике :)

Comment: @UModeL ответ супер.

Comment: @soledar10: нет ничего суперского там - Chrome и Edge норм, а FF снова не кажет... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз браузер позволяет достучаться в `#shadow-dom` через псевдоэлемент до блока (по сути, простого `<div>`), то остаётся найти какие свойства можно к нему применить. В комментариях Вам правильно подсказали - *white-space* и *font-size* - главные в решении этой задачи.

Тянем за нижний правый уголок, смотрим изменения, стилизуем по вкусу:

```css
input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::placeholder {
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  font-size: 33.33%;
  white-space: normal;
  /* Только для примера */
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Только для примера --> */ resizer { display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 8px; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; resize: horizontal; box-shadow: 0 0 2px #0008; }
```

```html
<resizer>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон для заказа обратной связи" style="width: 100%;">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон для заказа обратной связи" style="width: 66%;">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон для заказа обратной связи" style="width: 33%;">
</resizer>
```